# Find objects in array with same value property

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an array of bank accounts, which I receive from a GET request.

```html
<div class="card" *ngFor="let acc of accounts">{{acc.iban}}  ({{acc.currency}})>
```

Accounts array is for example like that:

```
this.accounts = [
    { iban : '123' , currency: 'EUR' },
    { iban:  '123' , currency: 'USD' },
    { iban:  '234' , currency: 'EUR' }
]
```

How can I dynamically find accounts with the same iban, remove one of them from the list, and add removed the account's currency to the other account ?

The expected output is:

```
this.accounts = [
    { iban: '123' , currency 'EUR, USD' },
    { iban:  '234' , currency: 'EUR' }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to merge the accounts with the same IBAN and join the currencies with a comma.

With `reduce`, you iterate on your `accounts` array and build an intermediate dictionary that maps the `iban` to the merged accounts, then with `Object.values()` you enumerate the values of the dictionary entries to return an array.

```js
const accounts = [
  { iban : '123' , currency: 'EUR' },
  { iban:  '123' , currency: 'USD' },
  { iban:  '234' , currency: 'EUR' }
];

const result = Object.values(accounts.reduce((acc, { iban, currency }) => {
  acc[iban] = acc[iban]
    ? { ...acc[iban], currency: acc[iban].currency + ', ' + currency }
    : { iban, currency };
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :)